# Удалить одно поле из HashMap при помощи Stream API

Tags: java, java-stream

У меня есть JSON с такой структурой:

```
{
  "template": "notifyChangeClaimState",
  "data": {
    "claimUid": "111-222-333",
    "attachments": [
      {
        "name": "Shana.jpg",
        "type": "jpg",
        "payload": "base-64 encoding"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

который я отображаю на `HashMap` (не дженерик). Этот `HashMap` находится в DTO-класе. Мне нужно трансформировать эту мапу в другую мапу так, чтобы она не содержала поле `attachments`. То есть результат должен быть таким:

```
{
  "template": "notifyChangeClaimState",
  "data": {
    "claimUid": "111-222-333"
  }
}
```

Я пытаюсь проделать конвертацию при помощи стримов:

```
Map<String, String> content = data.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(entry -> !"attachments".equals(entry.getKey()))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        Map.Entry::getKey,
                        Map.Entry::getValue
                ));
```

но такой код не компилируется:

```
Error:(27, 25) java: incompatible types: inference variable R has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: java.util.Map<K,U>
    lower bounds: java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>,java.lang.Object
```

а строки `Map.Entry::getKey` помечены как ошибка.

Как исправить этот код, чтобы он заработал?

Comment: а что если просто `data.remove("attachments")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Map<String, String> result = (Map<String, String>)data.keySet().stream()
            .filter(key -> !"attachments".equals(key))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(k->k, v->data.get(v)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Отфильтровываем ненужное и собираем с привидением типов `Map<Object, Object> -> Map<String, String>`

```
Map<String, String> content = data.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(entry -> !"attachments".equals(entry.getKey()))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        e -> e.getKey().toString(),
                        e -> e.getValue().toString()
                ));
```